# Split polygon manually- geometry validity error problem

Tags: qgis, splitting

I want to split a polygon feature manually using the Split tool in QGIS, but I am getting the error below

> no feature split done: The geometry is invalid. Please repair before
> trying to split.

I have checked the geometry using Vector-Geometry Tools-Check Geometry Validity and it reports 0 errors encountered.

I have tried creating a new simple multi-polygon layer and split works as suggested.

I can split the other polygons in this same layer, just not the one I'm interested in.

Any ideas for what else I can try?

Comment: It might help if you could paste the polygon and the splitting line as WKT.